# EPPlus when save excel it throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, epplus

I use EPPlus for generating Excel.

This is my action

```
 public ActionResult ExportReportToExcel()
    {
        var model = new ReportingViewModel();
        int numOfInvolvedCompanies, numOfRefusedCompanies, numOfSuccessfullCompanies, numOfEmployeesInvolved, projectsCount;
        model.Projects = db.GetProjectsReport(1, 1, out projectsCount, out numOfInvolvedCompanies, out numOfRefusedCompanies, out numOfSuccessfullCompanies, out numOfEmployeesInvolved);
        model.AllProjectsReport.NumberOfCompanyInvolved = numOfInvolvedCompanies;
        model.AllProjectsReport.NumberOfRefusedCompanies = numOfRefusedCompanies;
        model.AllProjectsReport.NumberOfSuccessfullParticipated = numOfSuccessfullCompanies;
        model.AllProjectsReport.NumberOfEmployeeInvolved = numOfEmployeesInvolved;

        ExcelPackage excel =  ExcelGenerator.GenerateReportingExcel(model);

        string excelName = "Reporting";

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            try
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + excelName + ".xlsx");
                excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Reporting");
    }
```

And this is my method which generates excel

```
        public static ExcelPackage GenerateReportingExcel(ReportingViewModel model)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Reporting");

            workSheet.TabColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            workSheet.DefaultRowHeight = 12;
            workSheet.Row(1).Height = 20;
            workSheet.Row(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
            workSheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;

            workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Name";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Sector";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "N of companies involved";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "N of refused companies";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "N of successful participated";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "N of employee involved";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 7].Value = "Start date";
            workSheet.Cells[1, 8].Value = "Finish date";



            int i = 2;
            foreach (var item in model.Projects)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value = item.Name;
                workSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value = item.SectorValues;
                workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = item.NumberOfCompanyInvolved;
                workSheet.Cells[i, 4].Value = item.NumberOfRefusedCompanies;
                workSheet.Cells[i, 5].Value = item.NumberOfSuccessfullParticipated;
                workSheet.Cells[i, 6].Value = item.NumberOfEmployeeInvolved;
                workSheet.Cells[i, 7].Value = item.StartDate;
                workSheet.Cells[i, 8].Value = item.FinishDate;
                i++;
            }


            workSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value = "Total";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Value = model.AllProjectsReport.NumberOfCompanyInvolved;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 4].Value = model.AllProjectsReport.NumberOfRefusedCompanies;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 5].Value = model.AllProjectsReport.NumberOfSuccessfullParticipated;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 6].Value = model.AllProjectsReport.NumberOfEmployeeInvolved;


            for (int colNum = 1; colNum <= 8; colNum++)
            {
                workSheet.Column(colNum).AutoFit();
            }

            return excel;
        }
    }
```

While trying save excel it throws NullReferenceException excel.SaveAs(memoryStream) line

[image]

The interesting side of this case is that it was working 2 days ago. And suddenly it stopped working and now throws this error.

Comment: Why, on Earth, do you have `catch(Exception e) { throw; }`?

Comment: @Enigmativity It is for debug purpose. The project is not in production yet.

Comment: That makes no sense. Allowing exceptions to bubble up normally is much better for debugging. Why do you feel that it is better to do it your way?

Comment: Why do you think it is not better than normal way?

Comment: Normal way? Not catching exceptions is the normal way to me. Catching the general `Exception` doesn't give you any ability to properly handle the exception as you don't know what went wrong - it also catches exceptions that you can't handle. If you get a `StackoverflowException` or `OutOfMemoryException` you just can't continue on. When an exception fires that's not handled you can deal with in in your IDE. That at the very least is  what makes debugging easier.

Comment: @Enigmativity you mean for debug purpose better practise is not writing try catch, then what do you think for production? So I want to say that I will write try catch for the production anyway. Don't you think that it would be better to write it before the production stage?

Comment: The only `try`/`catch` you should do in product is to catch **specific** exceptions and only those that you can meaningfully handle. You should never do `catch (Exception ...`. And meaningfully handle means to be able to recover and continue processing (not just exit or report an error).

Comment: Have a read of [Eric Lippert's Vexing Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: Thank you so much, I get the point. I will read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in the `GenerateReportingExcel` method.

In that method, you're returning an `ExcelPackage` object that's created in the using statement.

```
using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage())
{
      ...         
      return excel;
}
```

As disposable objects created by `using` will be disposed as soon as you exit the block, using this object outside of the method will cause an exception on `excel.SaveAs(memoryStream)` because `excel` has already been disposed.

You'll have to move some of your code around to resolve this. Two potential solutions (depending on what your needs are) are:

1. Move the `excel.SaveAs();` call into `GenerateReportingExcel()`, so it occurs within the `using` block that created `excel`
2. Remove the `using` block and manually create the `ExcelPackage` object that's returned, then call `excel.Dispose()` when you're done with it in `ExportReportToExcel()`

i.e.

```
public static ExcelPackage GenerateReportingExcel(ReportingViewModel)
{
    var excel = new ExcelPackage();
    ...
    return excel;
}
```

then in `ExportReportToExcel()`

```
try
{
    ...
    excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
    excel.Dispose();
    ...
}
```